# AJAX micropost's comments on the user page

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax, comments

On the user's page there are microposts and each of them have it's own comment form and comments. Using "Endless Page" railscast i'm trying to create "show more comments" button, which will load comments by AJAX. But it's not working.

**The problem** is in show.js.erb file because:

1) common pagination of comments (without AJAX) is working well

2) "show more button" is working well too. I tested it on the users list page

I think "show more comments" not working because it don'understand **<%= j render(comments) %> , <%= j will_paginate(comments) %>** and i should have here variables like **<%= j render(@comments) %> , <%= j will_paginate(@comments) %>**.

But when i try to write in my users_controller.rb

```
def show
    @micropost = Micropost.find(params[:micropost_id])
    @comments = @micropost.comments
end
```

it's not working because on my user's page there are many microposts and i have an error "Couldn't find micropost without an id". So in my microposts/_micropost.html.erb i had to use this

```
<% comments = micropost.comments.paginate(:per_page => 5, :page => params[:page]) %>

<%= render comments %>
```

Can anyone please help? How should i change my show.js.erb?

**users/show.html.erb**

```
<%= render @microposts %>
```

**microposts/_micropost.html.erb**

```
...
micropost's content
...

    <%= render 'comments/form', micropost: micropost %>

    <% comments = micropost.comments.paginate(:per_page => 5, :page => params[:page]) %>

    <div class="commentaries">
      <%= render comments %>
    </div>      

    <div id="append_and_paginate">
      <%= will_paginate comments, :class =>"pagination", :page_links => false %>
    </div>
```

**javascripts/users.js.coffee**

```
jQuery ->
  if $('.pagination').length
    $('#append_and_paginate').prepend('<a id="append_more_results" href="javascript:void(0);">Show more</a>');
    $('#append_more_results').click ->
      url = $('.pagination .next_page').attr('href')
      if url
        $('.pagination').text('Fetching more...')
        $.getScript(url)
```

**users/show.js.erb**

```
$('.commentaries').append('<%= j render(comments) %>');
<% if comments.next_page %>
  $('.pagination').replaceWith('<%= j will_paginate(comments) %>');
<% else %>
  $('.pagination').remove();
<% end %>
<% sleep 0.3 %>
```

Answer (score 0):

Bennington, in users/show.html.erb you have

But @microposts is not defined in your controller. What I think you want is to define @microposts as all the microposts associated with what, a User?

If so, you'd want something like `@microposts = Micropost.where(:user_id => current_user.id) or something.

Comment: No, it's defined. I just didn't post this because it all works great and problem not there. In my controller i have "@user = User.find(params[:id]) @microposts = @user.microposts.order("id").page(params[:page]).per_page(10)."

Comment: Sorry I don't know the <%= j render(comments) %> form. But <% comments = micropost.comments.paginate(:per_page => 5, :page => params[:page]) %>
seems unusual and I wonder shouldn't you put that in your controller?

If you need, you could create something like @paginated_comments = micropost.comments.paginate(:per_page => 5, :page => params[:page]) as an instance variable to feed to show.js.erb

Comment: Thanks for helping, yes it will be great if i could use "@micropost = Micropost.find(params[:micropost_id]) and @paginated_comments = @micropost.comments.paginate(:per_page => 5, :page => params[:page])" in my users_controller, but when i'm trying i have an error "Couldn't find micropost without an id"